# How to store and request a video/audio from specific position

Tags: mysql, node.js, storage, system-design

I want to be able to store a video/audio file in the server(doesn't matter how it gets uploaded), then store it(my guess is filesystem is better than db for this) and then when a client request it from a specific place/position(say, from 05:00) be able to return that specific piece of data to the client with some additional buffer(say from 05:00 to 06:00, or by actual size that it requires, I have no idea).

I thought of creating a JSON file instead of the actual video/audio file and place in it pieces of data of that file(blobs?) as value and a position(by seconds or what's better?) as keys. But I'm not sure if this is a good idea or what my alternatives are.

Would love to hear your thoughts and perhaps someone will tell how the big boys are implementing this.

Stack: MySQL/MongoDB, Node.js

Thanks

Comment: If the client uses the [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) header to specify a position (like HTML video controls do when skipping or searching), then [`res.sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) does everything automatically.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen That's interesting... Can you share a simple example plz? BTW: What if I want to implement this manually, how should I go about it? Is mine approach good, any caveats?